# Reacting on Head Event at Kinect

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I just wanted to ask how to handle the Event when for Example the Head comes in the Sensorview. I did read the Documentation, but dont find the Method for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event emitter from the SDK for your purpose. You need to pool Bodyframe and check is there any new skeleton is arrived. You can check out my repository if you need any reference, In there I build more complicated gestures such as click and swipe gestures.

https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction

Specially following places

https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction/blob/master/main.cpp#L187

https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction/blob/master/DepthBasics.cpp#L243